# Showing a set is closed in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

From Brezis chapter 8. When he goes through some examples of BVP, for one particular example (inhomogeneous Dirichlet problem) he constructs a set,
\begin{align}
K:=\{v\in H^{1}(I)\,|\,v(0)=\alpha\quad\text{and}\quad v(1)=\beta\},
\end{align}
where $I=(0,1)$. He states the set $K$ is closed and convex.

To show convexity, suppose $u,v\in K$. Then $tv+(1-t)u$ evaluated at $0$ and $1$ gives,
\begin{align}
tv(0)+(1-t)u(0)=\alpha,\\
tv(1)+(1-t)u(1)=\beta.
\end{align}
Hence, $tv+(1-t)u\in K$ and so $K$ is convex.

To show $K$ is closed is where I am a little stuck. Suppose $(v_{n})\in K$ is a convergent sequence with limit $v\in H^{1}(I)$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_{0}$ such that for $n>n_{0}$, $\|v_{n}-v\|_{H^{1}}<\varepsilon$. Now convergence in $H^{1}$ implies there exists a subsequence $(v_{n_{k}})$ which converges pointwise to $v$. Hence, since $v_{n_{k}}(0)=\alpha$ and $v_{n_{k}}(1)=\beta$ for all $k$ then $v(0)=\alpha$ and $v(1)=\beta$. Therefore $v\in K$ and so $K$ is closed.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: What exactly is $H^{1}(I)$?. In usual notations that is not a Hilbert space.

Comment: $H^{1}(I)=W^{1,\,2}(I)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$
   Av = v(a),\;\;\; Bv=v(b).
$$
These are continuous linear functionals on $H^1(I)$ because, for example,
$$
     v(a) = -\left.\frac{b-t}{b-a}v(t)\right|_{t=a}^{b}\\=
    -\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{b-t}{b-a}v(t)\right)dt \\
   = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{b-a}v(t)-\frac{b-t}{b-a}v'(t)dt,
$$
and
$$
        |Av|=|v(a)| \le C(\|v\|_{L^2}+\|v'\|_{L^2})
$$
Similary, $|Bv|\le C\|v\|_{H^2}$ for a constant $C$. Therefore, $K=\{ v\in H^1 : A(v)=B(v)=0 \}$ is closed as it is the intersection of two closed sets, both being the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under continuous linear functionals.

Comment: You lost me in the last part of your argument. I am referring to your re-definition of $K$ as the intersection of two closed sets. EDIT: Also how is your definition of $K$ equivalent to that in my post? I am not seeing it.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared $K = \{ v \in H^1 : v(0)= 0 \} \cap \{ v \in H^1 : v(1)=0 \}$ is the intersection of two closed sets--namely $A^{-1}\{0\}$ and $B^{-1}\{0\}$ where $Av = v(0)$ and $Bv=v(1)$. These are closed because $A$ and $B$ are continuous.

Comment: To be more precise and follow the OP's notation, it shouldn't be the inverse image of $\{0\}$. As you said, you should have $A(v):=v(0)$ and $B(v):=v(1)$, but then $K=A^{-1}(\{\alpha\}) \cap B^{-1}(\{\beta\})$, which is indeed closed because $A$ and $B$ are continuous.